# Unable to Get JSON to Read Properly Without Root and Cross Domain

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, sencha-touch, jsonp

I'm only asking this because I've seemingly tried everything I can find, and it has to be easier than I'm making it.

I'm working with Sencha Touch (EXTJS knowledge is still helpful). When I console.log the store, it shows no items/data. I am getting a good response from the store's load call, but it's not making it into the store. I appreciate the help.

Model:

```
Ext.define('NQT.model.NENEventsModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
    {name: 'regionId', type: 'int', mapping: 'regionId'},
    {name: 'regionName', type: 'string', mapping: 'regionName'},
    {name: 'state', type: 'string', mapping: 'state'},
    {name: 'switchId', type: 'int', mapping: 'switchId'},
    {name: 'switchName', type: 'string', mapping: 'switchName'}
]
});
```

Store:

```
Ext.define('NQT.store.NENEventsStore',
{
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
storeId: 'NENEventsStore',
config: {
    model: 'NQT.model.NENEventsModel',
    proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url: 'http://this_is_not_the_url.com:8080/rest/json',
        method: 'GET',
        pageParam: false,
        startParam: false,
        limitParam: false,
        noCache: false,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: ''
        }
    }
}
});
```

Part of view:

```
var eventsStore = Ext.create('NQT.store.NENEventsStore');

       {
            xtype: 'grid',
            titleBar: false,
            store: eventsStore,
            columns: [
                {text: 'regionId', dataIndex: 'regionId', width: 150},
                {text: 'regionName', dataIndex: 'regionName', width: 150},
                {text: 'state', dataIndex: 'state', width: 150},
                {text: 'switchId', dataIndex: 'switchId', width: 150},
                {text: 'switchName', dataIndex: 'switchName', width: 150}
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            docked: 'bottom',
            text: 'Reload Grid',
            handler: function () {
                console.log(eventsStore);
                eventsStore.load();
            }
        }
```

JSON Sample:

```
[{"regionId":1,"regionName":"NY Metro","state":"NJ","switchId":167,"switchName":"Jersey City 1"},
{"regionId":1,"regionName":"NY Metro","state":"NY","switchId":2029,"switchName":"Farmingdale 1"},
{"regionId":4,"regionName":"New England","state":"CT","switchId":203,"switchName":"Wallingford 1"}]
```

Comment: Your response doesn't look correct, see: http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.JsonP

Comment: You're right; it's missing the Ext.data.JsonP.callback.  I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Evan Trimboli pointed out, my response was not as good as I thought it was; it was missing the Ext.data.JsonP.callback that should have preceded it. I created a web service for the URL so I could make the call properly without being a security risk.

Part of the service:

```
<?php

$app->group('/secret', function () use ($app) {
$app->get('/getData', function () use ($app) {
    $callback = $app->request()->get('callback');
    $events = file_get_contents("http://example_url.com:8080/this/is/the/path");
    if(!empty($callback)){
        $app->contentType('application/javascript');
        echo sprintf("%s(%s)", $callback, $events);
    } else {
        echo $events;
    }
});
});

?>
```